# Commands 'aapt v' and 'android list' not found in terminal

Tags: android, ubuntu

I tried to run both command

```
aapt v 
android list
```

in Ubuntu 10.10 terminal but it states that both command are not found. What happened? I am installing Android SDK in my Ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to export everything to the classpath. To see if that's the case, run the command from the directory in which the tools are installed.

Comment: Thanks seretur. i have set the PATH in .profile too. Is this what you mean? Have tried to go to the path android-sdk/tools to run both command, but got the same result which is command not found.

Comment: Sure, try export PATH=$PATH{}:/path/to/android-sdk/tools and export PATH=$PATH{}:/path/to/android-sdk/tools:/path/to/android/platform-tools

Comment: I am very new to android development. May I know what is the difference between /pathtoandroidsdktools/ and /pathtoandroid/platformtools/ ?

Comment: In android-sdk "root" folder you have a tools subfolder and a platform-tools subfolder. You have to add both.